# Add RoboForm Application to Firefox

Tags: firefox, troubleshooting

The latest Firefox does not regonise RoboForm automatically, I can select from within Roboform to attach to Firefox, which it does, but it will not ''Remember'' and I have to attach manually each time I open Firefox, can this be altered?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not by the user. 
Wait for an update from roboform or use a supported version of Firefox.